# How to Enable and Disable Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have 4 buttons. Once on the page, I only want button 1 to show. Once button 1 has been clicked, it disappears and only button 2 is visible. Once button 2 has been clicked, it disappears and only button 3 shows. The same thing happens for button 5. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<script>
    function enableButton2() {
        document.getElementById("button2").disabled = false;
    }
function enableButton3() {
        document.getElementById("button3").disabled = false;
    }
function enableButton4() {
        document.getElementById("button4").disabled = false;
    }
function enableButton5() {
        document.getElementById("button5").disabled = false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="button 1" onclick="enableButton2()"                  
    onclick="hidden" />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="button 2" disabled onclick="enableButton3()"   
    onclick="hidden" />
<input type="button" id="button3" value="button 3" disabled 
    onclick="enableButton4()" onclick="hidden"  />
<input type="button" id="button4" value="button 4" disabled onclick="enableButton5()" 
    onclick="hidden" />
```

Comment: You have duplicate `onclick` attributes. Also, `onclick="hidden"` probably won't do anything

Comment: You can't have multiple `onclick` attributes. If you want to execute multiple statements, separate them with `;` inside a single attribute.

Comment: What is the actual question here? You've described what you want to happen but not what actually happens. I've created a JSFiddle for you here - http://jsfiddle.net/fZf34/

Comment: All buttons are shown and never disappears. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @user3217574 note that "disabled" means that something is visible, but that you can't interact with it. "Hidden" is entirely different and means that you can't see it and that you can't interact with it either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for a different function for each button. Make the ID of the next button a parameter of a single function. And to hide the first button, you need to set its `display` style, so pass `this` as another argument.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="button 1" onclick="enableButton(this, 'button2')" />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="button 2" disabled onclick="enableButton(this, 'button3')" />
<input type="button" id="button3" value="button 3" disabled onclick="enableButton(this, 'button4')" />
...
```

JS:

```
function enableButton(thisButton, nextButton) {
    thisButton.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(nextButton).disabled = false;
}
```